# Unable to set input values in List<String> when using a4j:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, repeat, ajax4jsf

I am displaying information from a `List<String>` on the UI inside editable textboxes using `<a4j:repeat>`. The user can click on a button on the UI to add mmore textboxes and add values into them (using an ajax call). My problem is that I am unable to set the value the user enters back into this `List<String>`

Below is the view

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{implMemoMBean.objA.objB.objC.listBillNumber}" var="item">                      
    <h:inputText class="list-bill"  value="#{item}" />                                          
</a4j:repeat>
```

The code in the bean to add when the user clicks on an 'Add' button is as follows

```
objA.objB().objC().getListBillNumber().add("");
```

This adds a `String` to the `List<String>` and rerenders the UI, which then displays an extra textbox. The value entered in this textbox is not being set on postback.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String` class is immutable and doesn't have a setter for the value. There's nothing like `String#set(newString)` or so. The getter is basically the `Object#toString()` method.

You need to get/set the value directly on the `List` by loop index instead. You can use the `rowKeyVar` attribute to define the EL variable name of the current loop index.

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{implMemoMBean.objA.objB.objC.listBillNumber}" rowKeyVar="i">                       
    <h:inputText class="list-bill" value="#{implMemoMBean.objA.objB.objC.listBillNumber[i]}" />                                           
</a4j:repeat>
```

Note that you don't need a setter for the `listBillNumber`. EL will get the item by `List#get(index)` and set the item by `List#add(index,item)`.

Comment: Thank you so much Balu. That solved my problem. Kinda feel a li'l embarrassed that i din even understand what the problem was. This worked out just awesome